# asp:GridView with Multiple Header Rows Using HTML

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, gridview, postback

I have an asp:GridView that I need to display 2 header rows...The first for days (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, etc), and the second to display 'Normal Time' and 'Overtime'.

I've done this by dynamically adding the code to gridview_RowDataBound, the problem is when the page re-loads/does a postback then the row that I added falls away and the GridView no longer fires the javascript functions used on it. This only seems to happen sometimes though, I have no idea why.

The page is basically a timesheet entry form. The user selects a date from a datepicker (the page then re-loads and this is where things sometime seem to go crazy).

This is what my grid looks like now:

[image]

Using the following code:

```
                Table tbl = e.Row.Parent as Table;
            var row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            TableCell cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 3;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Monday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Tuesday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Wednesday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Thursday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Friday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Saturday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "Sunday";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = "";
            cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            row.Cells.Add(cell);

            tbl.Rows.AddAt(tbl.Rows.Count - 1, row);
```

But I'd like to know if there's anyway I can get the grid in the image to look that way with HTML instead of doing it in code-behind, since this seems to break the grid more than anything else.

Thanks

(I should add that the 'Normal' / 'OT' header rows are set in the html using:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OT" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
```

Comment: A ListView is a much better choice, assuming you can use 3.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following in your <EditItemTemplate> tag:

```
<EditItemTemplate>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>Monday</td >
        <td colspan=2>Tuesday</td >
        <td colspan=2>Wednesday</td >
        <td colspan=2>Thursday</td >
        <td colspan=2>Friday</td >
        <td colspan=2>Saturday</td >
        <td colspan=2>Sunday</td >
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Normal</td>
        <td>OT</td>
        <td>Normal</td>
        <td>OT</td>

        ...
        ...
        ...
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <TD><asp:Textbox ID="txtBox1" runat="server"/></TD>
        <TD><asp:Textbox ID="txtBox2" runat="server"/></TD>
        <TD><asp:Textbox ID="txtBox3" runat="server"/></TD>
        <TD><asp:Textbox ID="txtBox4" runat="server"/></TD>

        ...
        ...
        ...

    </tr>
</table>

</EditItemTemplate>
```

You can fill out the rest of it in the ... (dot dots)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, it definitely is a better solution for now to just get the functionality right. Look and feel will have to wait.